# sum of element in a table jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i've a php file that create a table like this

```
<table style="text-align:center; margin-top:20px;" align="center" cellpadding="5"> 
<caption><u><b>Ordine del 22-10-2015 delle ore 16:08:38<b/></u><br /></caption> 
<thead style="background-color:#EBE9E9"> 
<tr> 
    <th scope="col">Prodotto</th> 
    <th scope="col">Quantit&agrave;</th> 
    <th scope="col">Prezzo</th> 
    <th scope="col">Totale parziale</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody style="background-color:F5FFFF"> 
<tr> 
    <td>Coca Cola</td> 
    <td> x1</td> 
    <td>1,50 &euro;</td> 
    <td>1,50 &euro;</td> 
    <td><input type="hidden" class="toadd" value="1.50"></td>
</tr><tr> 
    <td>Limonata</td> 
    <td> x1</td> 
    <td>1,50 &euro;</td> 
    <td>1,50 &euro;</td> 
        <td><input class="toadd" type="hidden" value="1.50"></td>
    </tr><tr> 
    <td>Maxibon</td> 
    <td> x1</td> 
    <td>2,00 &euro;</td> 
    <td>2,00 &euro;</td> 
        <td><input class="toadd" type="hidden" value="1.50"></td>
    </tr><tr> 
    <td>Pirulo</td> 
    <td> x1</td> 
    <td>1,00 &euro;</td> 
    <td>1,00 &euro;</td> 
    <td><input class="toadd" type="hidden" value="1.50"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Totale</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="totale"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Now the php file create more and more table depending on row presents in bd

I use this jquery code to calculate the sum of element with the class="toadd"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var sum = 0;

$('.toadd').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});

$('.totale').text(sum.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
style: 'currency', 
currency: 'EUR', 
minimumFractionDigits: 2 
}));
```

the problem is that when there's only 1 table it works perfect, but when tables are more than one, it gives to me the total of all table.

I need only the total for each table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to iterate all the tables and traverse each table element to calculate/set values,

```
$("table").each(function(){
   $('.toadd', this).each(function() {
     sum += Number($(this).val());
   });
  $('.totale', this).text(sum.toLocaleString('it-IT', {
    style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'EUR', 
    minimumFractionDigits: 2 
  }));
});
```